# Laravel 7 : Redirect to different logins on different guards

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-7, guard

i'm using the auth middleware and creating and admin guard for controlling the admin access. Im having some problems when im trying to access to the admin routes, i would like to redirect the unathenticated trafict associated to the admins routes to  an   /admin/login page, but instead of that, it redirect me to the /login page.
I don't know how to get the guards associated to a route in the class Authenticate.

```
 protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('login');
        }
    }
}
```

that's the code, i would like to be something like :

```
 protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            if(Auth::guard('admin'))
               return route('admin.login);
            else
               return route(login);
        }
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work, 'cos the only parameter that i have is the $request.

Those are my routes...

```
//Admin Routes
Route::middleware(['auth:admin'])->group(function () {
Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin');
Route::get('/newDoncente', 'AdminController@addDocenteView')->name('newDocente');

//Docentes Routes
Route::get('/docentes', 'Docente\DocenteController@getDocentesView')->name('getDocentesView');
Route::get('/editDocente/{id}', 'Docente\DocenteController@editDocenteView')->name('editDocentesView');
Route::get('/docentesTables', 'Docente\DocenteController@getDocentesDatatables')->name('getDocentesTables');
Route::get('/docente/{id}', 'Docente\DocenteController@getDocenteView')->name('getDocenteView');
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can put condition based on routes.

Comment: how? i can patch it adding /admin/ path to all the routes... 'cos on the request i can get the path, but i don't know if that's correct.

Answer (score 5):

I've been looking for a guard based answer, where I was looking to check the guard than redirects based on the guard type. However I couldn't find a solution.

However, I found another solution that gets the job done but it isn't as dynamic as the answer I'm looking for. However, it's working fine for me

in

> App\Http\Middleware\Authinticate.php

class, add the following code:

```
protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            if($request->is('admin') || $request->is('admin/*'))
            return route('admin.login');
            
            return route('login');
        }
    }
```

Also, don't forget to prefix all admin routes with admin/ .
Hope this answer helps you.

Answer (score 4):

go to the app/Exception/Handler.php

use this class

```
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
```

and add this function in the class

```
    protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        if (request()->expectsJson()) {
            return Response()->json(['error' => 'UnAuthorized'], 401); //exeption for api
        }

        $guard = data_get($exception->guards(), 0);
        switch ($guard) {
            case 'admin':
                $login = 'admin.login';
                break;
            default:
                $login = 'login';
                break;
        }
        return redirect()->guest(route($login));
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I overrode the **handle** method so I can get the guards from it as follows:

```
protected $guards = [];

public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
{
    $this->guards = $guards;

    return parent::handle($request, $next, ...$guards);
}
protected function redirectTo($request)
{
    if (in_array("admin", $this->guards)) {
        return "admin/login";
    }

}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, simple and elegant with no side effects. Thank you!

Comment: Glad this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i've resolve it, i guess that's quite a good approach. I create a middleware and i asked for the auth guard on the middleware.

First I create the middleware

```
class IsAdmin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
    
        if (Auth::guard('admin')->check()) 
        return $next($request);
        else 
        return redirect('/admin/login');

    }
}
```

Then I put the middleware in the Kernel file

```
 protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'isAdmin' => \App\Http\Middleware\IsAdmin::class,
```

Last, i change the middleware for the routes

```
Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin');
```

Now it's working fine, but if you have a better solution, i really wanted to know it.